# Angular - Activating a class when another class is activated by JS

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ng-class, angular-ng-if

I want to activate a class xyz when class xy is activated using ngClass.
I want to implement this scenario:

```
if class xyz is in the tag
activate class xy
ngClass="'xyz' then xy"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Primeng-datatable checkboxed selection, I want to show a customized
>   tick mark. So when checkbox is toggled, I want to activate and
>   deactivate a specific class when checkboxes are toggled.

In Order to achieve that you can do this 
in html

```
<p-checkbox (onChange)="onChange($event)" inputId="checkBoxId" name="groupname" value="val1" [(ngModel)]="selectedValues"></p-checkbox>
```

in ts

```
    onChange(checked:boolean){
     let el=document.getElementById('checkBoxId');
if(checked){
      if(el)
      {
       el.classList.Add('xyz');
      }
     }
else{
   if(el)
      {
       el.classList.Remove('xyz');
      }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If **xzy** is triggered with `SOMELOGIC`, why not trigger **xy** class with the same `SOMELOGIC`? Try it, i think that's logical. Good Luck :)

Comment: So i have to apply the logic in .ts class?

Comment: Show me the code line, where you bind a **class** to a tag and I will answer you correctly

Comment: In Primeng-datatable checkboxed selection, I want to show a customized tick mark. So when checkbox is toggled, I want to activate and deactivate a specific class when checkboxes are toggled.

Comment: Honestly I don't know how to use PrimeNG, I will try to understand tho. If any success, I will comment here. Thanks.

Comment: I think I got what you want. I will comment the example

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" [(selection)]="selectedCars3" dataKey="vin" [paginator]="true" [rows]="5" [headerCheckboxToggleAllPages]="true">
    <p-header [ngClass]="{'xy': someVar}">Checkbox Multiple Selection with Paging</p-header>
    <p-column [ngClass]="{'xyz': someVar}" [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
    <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
    <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
    <p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>
    <p-column field="color" header="Color"></p-column>
    <p-footer>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let car of selectedCars3" style="text-align: left">{{car.vin + ' - ' + car.brand + ' - ' + car.year + ' - ' + car.color}}</li>
        </ul>
    </p-footer>
</p-dataTable>
```

On `p-header` is applied `xy` class. It triggers when **someVar** is true. On `p-column` is applied `xyz`, it also triggers when **someVar** is true. So the point is, if you want to trigger **xyz** when **xy** is triggered, just trigger **xyz** with variable that is triggering **xy**. Hope it helps :)